# Consuming WCF services from android with JSON format

Tags: android, json

I've been building an android application which was consuming wcf services (soap-based with basicHttpbinding).So in order to do so i've used ksoap library.Now it is important that we must switch the wcf on the server returning JSON it needs to stay soap-based,not restful.Is it necessary that I change the binding too?Also i've noticed in other posts in this forum that using WSbinding isn't compatible with android is this true?Thank you in advance.